# Exceptions while using -source 5 or higher to enable generics

Tags: java, ant, version

I got few exceptions related to source 5 or higher to enable generics when I write `ant all rebuild` in cmd.

I have latest *jdk1.7*. I have apache *ant1.8.4* where I modified source and target to 1.6 in `ant.pom` and several other files but still I encountered the same exception. I have copied `ant.bat` file in folder where I compile the code.

Comment: "the same exception" - which you haven't bothered to tell us... Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list (Are these even exceptions, or are they compile-time errors?)

Comment: I suspect its not an exception.

Comment: What are the exceptions? Is there an error message? Does your `build.xml` execute at all, or do you get an error when trying to run Ant itself? If you can run the `build.xml` and it's failing on the compile, What does your build.xml `<javac>` task look like? It'd be easier to help if we could see these exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use target `1.5` (you cannot use the 5.0 version and there was no version "5" as such) you have to set the -source to be `1.5` as well.

Comment: You may also need the Java rt.jar and set `bootclasspath` to that too. You get a warning about this when you compile with JDK 1.7 and don't set the `bootclasspath`.

Comment: Agreed, If you want to compile for Java 1.5, it is far simpler to use Java 1.5.  (You end up having to use it's libraries to compile against any way)

Comment: Where would I set bootclasspath?

Comment: You set it on the class path see the java command line help pages to see how.